# Is this an acceptable implementation of the insertion sort algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

The following Java implementation of the insertion sort algorithm appears on page 28 of *Java Programming Interviews Exposed* by Noel Markham:

```
public static List<Integer> insertSort(final List<Integer> numbers) {
    final List<Integer> sortedList = new LinkedList<>();
    originalList: for (Integer number : numbers) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedList.size(); i++) {
            if (number < sortedList.get(i)) {
                sortedList.add(i, number);
                continue originalList;
            }
        }
        sortedList.add(sortedList.size(), number);
    }
    return sortedList;
}
```

A coworker of mine who reviewed this code found it unacceptable as a response to an interview question posed as "Please implement the insertion sort algorithm". He felt that an array would be a more appropriate data structure for the sorted list. But, as Markham explains on the same page:

> A linked list is very efficient in adding elements in the middle of
>   the list, simply by rearranging the pointers of the nodes in the list.
>   If an ArrayList had been used, adding elements to the middle would be
>   expensive. An ArrayList is backed by an array, so inserting at the
>   front or middle of the list means that all subsequent elements must be
>   shifted along by one to a new slot in the array. This can be very
>   expensive if you have a list with several million rows, especially if
>   you are inserting early in the list.

Is this an acceptable implementation?

Comment: Insertion sort is in-place; why are you creating another array?

Comment: On the same page Markham says "Notice that the method returns a new List unlike the bubble sort, which sorted the elements in place. This is mainly the choice of the implementation." But, consistent with what you are saying the Wikipedia description of Insertion Sort says it is "in place": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort . I don't know who is correct.

Answer (score 1):

consider the following pseudo-code for insertion sort:

```
for i ← 1 to length(A) - 1
    j ← i
    while j > 0 and A[j-1] > A[j]
        swap A[j] and A[j-1]
        j ← j - 1
    end while
end for
```

Source:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

1) so, in the process, you hold each element and compare it with its previous element and swap if the previous element is greater than the current element and this keeps on happening till the condition doesn't satisfy.

2) the algorithm works by swapping element by element and not by inserting the element right at the place where it is supposed to be.note:-each swap is o(1).

3)hence, in this form, if you use a list, you have 2 operations to do, connect the predecessor and the current element and vice-versa along with the neighbouring elements. On the other hand, sorted array would take only one step.

4)therefore, in this approach, a sorted array makes more sense than a list.

> Now, if the approach of insertion sort was directly inserting the current element at the place where it is fitting, a linked list would have worked better.

Note:- a sorted array or sorted linked list, the overall proces would be same, it is the intermediary steps that make the difference than the sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, what states Markham could be good common sense: insertion in a linked list should not cost much (allocation of a new node, a few reference assignments), and even the insertion at the end of the list is inexpensive since `LinkedList` is actually a double-linked list and keep a reference on the last element.

The argument between inserting a new node (for the `LinkedList`) and shifting part of the array (for `ArrayList`) has, at least, to be tested because `ArrayList#add(int i, E)` use `System.arrayCopy()` which should be really optimised for this kind of job.

You can ear/see everywhere "beware of micro-benchmark". Well, I would say that when you want to have a rough idea of what is going on, micro-benchmarking can give you some hints...

Following is a micro-bench of the 2 methods you wanted to compare, plus the `Collections.sort()` to have some reference timing. Note *insertion sort* is in average `O(N^2)`, compare to *tim sort* of the `Collections` which is `O(Nlog(N))`.

In the proposed implementation of *insertion sort*, I just pass the sorted list implementation in order to use the same function for both tests.

```
public static List<Integer> insertSort(final List<Integer> numbers,
                                       final List<Integer> sortedList) {
    //final List<Integer> sortedList = new ArrayList<>();
    originalList: for (Integer number : numbers) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedList.size(); i++) {
            if (number < sortedList.get(i)) {
                sortedList.add(i, number);
                continue originalList;
            }
        }
        sortedList.add(sortedList.size(), number);
    }
    return sortedList;
}
```

Then following is a method that will measure the time spent sorting a list of random ints and print it:

```
public static List<Integer> bench(List<Integer> ints, String tag,
                                  Function<List<Integer>, List<Integer>> sortf) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    List<Integer> sortedInts = sortf.apply(ints);
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(String.format("type: %6s size: %7d time(ms): %5d", 
                                     tag, ints.size(), (end-start)/1000000));
    return sortedInts;
}
```

The function `microBench()` will loop through increasing array sizes and sort the same random array with the 3 methods and compare the sorted lists.

```
public static void microBench(int start, int end, int step) {
    for (int m = start; m <= end; m+=step) {
        List<Integer> ints = new Random()
             .ints(m, 0, m).boxed()
             .collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<Integer> l1 = bench(ints, "coll", (List<Integer> l) -> { 
            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(l);
            Collections.sort(list);
            return list;
        });

        List<Integer> l2 = bench(ints, "array", (List<Integer> l) ->
            insertSort(l, new ArrayList<Integer>()));
        if (!l1.equals(l2)) {
            System.out.println("Oooops array");
        }

        List<Integer> l3 = bench(ints, "linked", (List<Integer> l) -> 
            insertSort(l, new LinkedList<Integer>()));
        if (!l1.equals(l3)) {
            System.out.println("Oooops linked");
        }
    }
}
```

All this called from a `main`. Start with an array of 500 and then increase the size until **5,000** (quite small size indeed!). Execution env. is MBP 2,5 GHz Intel Core i7.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    microBench(1000, 5000, 1000);
}

type:   coll size:    1000 time(ms):     1
type:  array size:    1000 time(ms):     8
type: linked size:    1000 time(ms):    66
type:   coll size:    2000 time(ms):     1
type:  array size:    2000 time(ms):     2
type: linked size:    2000 time(ms):   507
type:   coll size:    3000 time(ms):     2
type:  array size:    3000 time(ms):     4
type: linked size:    3000 time(ms):  2283
type:   coll size:    4000 time(ms):     1
type:  array size:    4000 time(ms):     9
type: linked size:    4000 time(ms):  6866
type:   coll size:    5000 time(ms):     1
type:  array size:    5000 time(ms):    13
type: linked size:    5000 time(ms): 14842
```

No need to draw a picture to understand insertion sort *with* `LinkedList` is not a winner! **14 seconds to sort 5000 ints**. But insertion sort *with* `ArrayList` is not so bad.

I removed the bench on the `LinkedList` and push a bit with a max array size of **100,000**.

```
    microBench(10000, 100000, 10000);

type:  array size:   10000 time(ms):    70
type:   coll size:   20000 time(ms):     6
type:  array size:   20000 time(ms):   290
type:   coll size:   30000 time(ms):     8
type:  array size:   30000 time(ms):   382
type:   coll size:   40000 time(ms):     6
type:  array size:   40000 time(ms):   667
type:   coll size:   50000 time(ms):     7
type:  array size:   50000 time(ms):   984
type:   coll size:   60000 time(ms):     8
type:  array size:   60000 time(ms):  1521
type:   coll size:   70000 time(ms):    10
type:  array size:   70000 time(ms):  2172
type:   coll size:   80000 time(ms):    12
type:  array size:   80000 time(ms):  2729
type:   coll size:   90000 time(ms):    13
type:  array size:   90000 time(ms):  3587
type:   coll size:  100000 time(ms):    15
type:  array size:  100000 time(ms):  4528
```

**4.5 sec vs 15 msec**. That's no surprise, insertion sort is still O(N^2) compared to tim sort/merge sort O(NlogN)...

Since Markham was writing about 1,000,000 element arrays, I just went with the bench on the only implementation (from the 3 tested) which can decently do it, and removed the insertion sort with `ArrayList`

```
    microBench(100000, 1000000, 100000);

type:   coll size:  100000 time(ms):    41
type:   coll size:  200000 time(ms):    36
type:   coll size:  300000 time(ms):    58
type:   coll size:  400000 time(ms):    82
type:   coll size:  500000 time(ms):   108
type:   coll size:  600000 time(ms):   126
type:   coll size:  700000 time(ms):   152
type:   coll size:  800000 time(ms):   178
type:   coll size:  900000 time(ms):   199
type:   coll size: 1000000 time(ms):   223
```

**223 msec** for 1,000,000.

Conclusion, beware of what people can write and test yourself when it can be done! - by the way, your co-worker was right. 
And, if you have to sort, insertion sort, is *usually* not the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to linearly iterate the linked list in the inner loop instead of `get(i)`, since `LinkedList` does not support `RandomAccess`.
Otherwise every element access needs `i` steps to find the corresponding element and benchmarks as the one in the other answer get misleading results when comparing the implementation eg to `ArrayList`.

```
public static List<Integer> insertSort(final List<Integer> numbers) {
    final LinkedList<Integer> sortedList = new LinkedList<>();
    originalList: for (Integer number : numbers) {
        int i = 0;
        for (Integer compare : sortedList) {
            if (number < compare) {
                sortedList.add(i, number);
                continue originalList;
            }
            ++i;
        }
        sortedList.addLast(number);
    }
    return sortedList;
}
```